# WnRT SQLite library routine called out of sequence error

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm building a windows 8.1 app and I use SQLite to persist application status but I'm facing a  "library routine called out of sequence" error. I'm build on x86 platform.

Comment: There is an error in your code.

Comment: the code was working already but it generate that error suddenly, I don't know why actually, but is it because of something related to database creation or is it because of targeting platform as I'm building against x86 and my machine 64

Comment: Both are possible, but I think it's more likely that it's more likely there's an error in your code. Debug it and post the code that is causing the exception so that we can take a look. As to x86 vs x64, I doubt that's the issue, but do make sure that you have separate build profiles for x86 and x64. You should be able to test both on your machine though.